# Davening Ma'ariv Early on Friday Night

Tags: tefilla, maariv, leil-shabbat

How is it that we can daven Ma'ariv early before Shkia on Friday night when bringing Shabbos early?

Differently then the rest of the week?

People that usually daven after tzais hakochavim during the week on shabos daven after plag haminha

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Zachary. Thanks for sharing this question. Perhaps consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site.

Comment: Why would you think we can't? If you [edit] your post to elaborate on what you find confusing and why, people will better be able to get you the answers you seek. Also try and clarify who is the 'we' that does this, as not all do it, and clarifying the subject of your post can also help people find answers from the perspective you seek.

Comment: I think that's a dupe. It asks about references for praying Maariv after Plag with a Minyan. If it isn't, please [edit] here to clarify the differences, in addition to addressing my above comment.

Comment: Zachary, welcome to Mi Yodeya. To expand on what @DoubleAA said above, don't assume that everyone on this site knows what you're talking about. It may be possible to assume that common terms (like Shabbos) are understood. But, although you want an answer from someone who can answer your question - and that person should already be an expert and understand what you mean, this question will be up on the internet indefinitely, and others with the same or similar question should be able to get value out of yours - and any answer(s) that may be posted.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't think this is a dupe of that. That's asking *whether* something is ok for an individual. This is asking *why* it is permissible (an assumption, to be sure) and asking generally (not necessarily individually). Also, that question is a poor example of a properly formatted and presented question.

Comment: Erev shabos is different see  http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/267/2.htm

Comment: @SethJ The other asks about both cases: individual and communal.

Comment: @hazoriz Not all agree to that. It's actually a rather difficult position. Why does he say there is a Mitzva to say Maariv early when he also thinks one can accept Shabbat without Maariv?

Comment: @DoubleAA see the end of the first machatis hashekel (on the first dirvrai hamaskil) on the first sif koton of the mogen AvroHom http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1465